# How to use variables withen the [RegularExpression] in .NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am working on a webapplication where'd need to validate my e-mail input field with additional regular expressions.

#### Model.cs ###

```
private string _regexOne = (@"myfirstregex")
private string _regexTwo = (@"mysecondregex");

public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [RegularExpression(((_regexOne)|(_regexTwo)), ErrorMessage = "My custom error message")] /* this line contains an error */
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I'd need those regular expressions a few more times, so I want to declare them globally so I don't have to copy paste them everywhere. 
However, this code above is wrong and doesn't run.

So my question(s) is/are: Can I use variable of regex in this attribute? If yes, what would the syntax be?

Comment: Why don't you code your own attribute inheriting from RegularExpressionAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

Define the regular expressions as `Constants` and those can be used attribute declaration. See below sample :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Program
{
    public const string Regex1 = "abc";
    public const string Regex2 = "xyz";
    public const string CompositeRegex = Regex1 + "|" + Regex2;

    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Regex1);
        Console.WriteLine(Regex2);
        Console.WriteLine(CompositeRegex);      
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    [RegularExpression(Program.Regex1  + "|" + Program.Regex2)]
    public string TestProperty {get; set;}
}
```

You can compile and see the code in this

[Live Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xwd4OQ).